# Spring Boot Servlet Registration

Tags: spring-boot, servlets

I am migrating a traditional Servlet/JSP application to Spring Boot.

This is the current structure of a servlet class

```
public class CreateAbsenceServlet extends CommonServlet
```

I was able to register this servlet as bean in spring boot configuratin class as below

```
@Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean CreateAbsenceServletRegistrationBean() {
    ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean(
        new CreateAbsenceServlet(), "/createAbsence");

    return bean;
  }
```

Question is how do i register CommonServlet because there  is no direct mapping for this servlet as its an abstract class which extends HTTPServlet and has bunch of servlet lifecycle methods

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public abstract class CommonServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        prepareExecute(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        prepareExecute(request, response);
    }

    protected abstract void execute(HttpSession session,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            PrintWriter out, BufferedReader reader) throws Exception;

            protected void prepareExecute(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
            response.setContentType("text/html");

            execute(session, request, response, out, reader);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (ServletException.class.isInstance(ex)) {
                throw (ServletException) ex;
            } else {
                throw new ServletException(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getParameterValue(HttpServletRequest req, String parameter) {
        Enumeration<String> parameterNames = req.getParameterNames();
        String paramValue = "";

        while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String paramName = parameterNames.nextElement();

            if (parameter.equalsIgnoreCase(paramName)) {
                String[] paramValues = req.getParameterValues(paramName);

                for (int i = 0; i < paramValues.length; i++) {
                    paramValue = paramValues[i];
                }
            }
        }

        return paramValue;
    }

    public void sendError(HttpServletResponse response, String errorMessage,
            int status) throws IOException {

        response.setStatus(status);
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following are my observations and suggestions :

- Can you check to see if the methods in class are eligible to be
  converted to a    Listener or Filter using the `@WebFilter` or
  `@WebListener` annotation.
- The error message can be handled using spring boot `@ControllerAdvice`
  and `@ExceptionHandler` annotations separately.

you can find a detailed explanation on how to do this from this post here :
[How can I register a servlet with Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55978959/how-can-i-register-a-servlet-with-spring-boot/56015257#56015257)