# How can I register a servlet with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, servlets

This code don't work

I have a web.xml that needs to be translated into a spring boot

```
    <servlet>       
            <servlet-name>page-resolver</servlet-name>       
            <servlet-class>com.bk.ForwardServlet</servlet-class>         
            <init-param>
                <param-name>page</param-name>
                <param-value>/index.jsp</param-value>         
            </init-param>         
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>                            
        <servlet-name>page-resolver</servlet-name>         
        <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/qmgr/*</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>
```

and this class

```
@WebServlet
public class ForwardServlet extends HttpServlet {

private String page;

@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    super.init(config);
    page = config.getInitParameter("page");
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    req.getRequestDispatcher(page).forward(req, resp);
}
}
```

I wrote code that registers this bean but it doesn't work and I don't understand why

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigureWeb implements ServletContextInitializer {

private void registerServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {
    ServletRegistrationBean serviceServlet =
            new ServletRegistrationBean(new ForwardServlet(), "/index.html","/login","/qmgr/*");

    serviceServlet.addUrlMappings("/index.jsp");
}

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    registerServlet(servletContext);
}
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all check and verify that all your resources are being kept in the correct directory.For spring-boot the jsp pages are to be kept in the directory `src->main->webapp->WEB-INF->view->*.jsp` .

You should have the following dependencies added in pom to compile the jsp properly when using embedded tomcat :

```
<!-- JSTL -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- To compile JSP files -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now we need to tell spring where the jsp files reside, we can have two approaches for this :

**Add entries in application.properties**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Here we can specify the folder where the jsp files are to be expected, as well as define the view.
or

**Configure InternalResourceViewResolver to serve JSP pages**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

Now for **registering** **servlets** **:**

`ServletRegistrationBean` is used to register Servlets in **Servlet 3.0 +** container. We need to create a bean of `ServletRegistrationBean` in our JavaConfig. Find some methods of ServletRegistrationBean used to configure a Servlet.
**setServlet():** Sets the servlet to be registered.
**addUrlMappings():** Add URL mappings for the Servlet.
**setLoadOnStartup:** Sets priority to load Servlet on startup.

Suppose we have two Servlets as `HelloCountryServlet` and `HelloStateServlet` then we will register them with Spring Boot using ServletRegistrationBean as following :

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {
   @Bean    
   public ServletRegistrationBean<HttpServlet> countryServlet() {
       ServletRegistrationBean<HttpServlet> servRegBean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>();
       servRegBean.setServlet(new HelloCountryServlet());
       servRegBean.addUrlMappings("/country/*");
       servRegBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
       return servRegBean;
   }
   @Bean    
   public ServletRegistrationBean<HttpServlet> stateServlet() {
       ServletRegistrationBean<HttpServlet> servRegBean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>();
       servRegBean.setServlet(new HelloStateServlet());
       servRegBean.addUrlMappings("/state/*");
       servRegBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
       return servRegBean;
   }   
}
```

For every Servlet we create a ***ServletRegistrationBean*** bean.
And the servlet class will look like :

```
public class HelloCountryServlet extends HttpServlet   {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        doGet(request,response);
    }
        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<h3>Hello India!</h3>");   
    }
}
```

This is one approach.

**Another method** to register servlets in spring-boot is using annotations : **@ServletComponentScan** and **@WebServlet**. `@ServletComponentScan` in Spring Boot will scan Servlets annotated with `@WebServlet`, Filters annotated with `@WebFilter` and Listeners annotated with `@WebListener`.The annotation @ServletComponentScan is used on JavaConfig at class level. @ServletComponentScan scans Servlets, Filters and Listeners ***only using an embedded web server***. Find the Servlets annotated with @WebServlet.

So the earlier *HelloCountryServlet* servlet can be provided as :

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/country/*", loadOnStartup = 1)
public class HelloCountryServlet extends HttpServlet   {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
         doGet(request,response);
    }
        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
             response.setContentType("text/html");
             PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
         out.println("<h3>Hello India!</h3>");  
    }
}
```

and provide the ServletComponentScan annotation like :

```
@ServletComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootAppStarter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAppStarter.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not required to register a servlet, you could add the forwarding to the `ViewControllerRegistry`

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/index.html").setViewName("forward:/index.jsp");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("forward:/index.jsp");
        registry.addViewController("/qmgr/**").setViewName("forward:/index.jsp");
    }
}
```

You could combine the three `addViewController`s into one using `AntPathMatcher` patterns

> Map a view controller to the given URL path (or pattern) in order to
>   render a response with a pre-configured status code and view.
>
> Patterns like "/admin/**" or "/articles/{articlename:\w+}" are
>   allowed. See [AntPathMatcher](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html) for more details on the syntax.

Personally I think separating them is more readable